# Knockout dynamc load subtree

Tags: knockout.js, tree, subtree

I am trying to make dynamic load sub tree with knockout. 
My idea is show only root items at default. When I click to item, it dynamic load subitems (with ajax). When i click to this subitem it dynamic loads their childs ..... The tree sholud be multilevel (min 5 level).

Any idea how to do this?

I tried to save the items into observableArray. The problem is every time when I choose any root item it has the same childs. How to split childs for each parent?

```
me.categories = ko.observableArray();

me.loadCategories = function () {
      api.call("GET", "/api/...").done((result) => {
        me.categories(result);
      });
    };

<div data-bind="foreach: categories">
<ul id="myUL">
<li>
<span class="caret" data-bind="click: $parent.getSubCategories.bind ($data, id()), text: name"></span>
<ul class="nested" data-bind="foreach: $parent.subcategories">
<li>
<span class="caret" data-bind="click: $parentContext.$parent.getSubCategories1.bind ($data, id), text: name"></span>
<ul class="nested" data-bind="foreach: $parentContext.$parent.subcategories1">
<li>
<span class="caret" data-bind="click: $parents[2].getSubCategories1.bind ($data, id), text: name"></span>
<ul class="nested" data-bind="foreach: $parents[2].subcategories1">
<li>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to render tree is to have data in form of tree and same for visual side.

- for data storage I would use  array of arrays of arrays...
- for visualisation I would use recursive component

In this simple example I use observableArray only for root items = your categories. After clicking any item new array of subcategories are appended after the clicked item as simple JavasSript array and whole tree is refreshed using `valueHasMutated`. Somewhat crude, but hopefully you can see the basic principle.

```js
ko.components.register('myList', {
    template: 
      "<ul data-bind='foreach: $data'>" + 
        "<!-- ko if: typeof $data === 'string' -->" +
          "<li data-bind='text: $data, click: $root.expand.bind(null, $parent, $index())'></li>" +
        "<!-- /ko -->" +
        "<!-- ko if: typeof $data !== 'string' -->" +
          "<!-- ko component: {name: 'myList', params: $data} -->" +
          "<!-- /ko -->" +
        "<!-- /ko -->" +
      "</ul>"
});

var data = ko.observableArray([
  "node1",
  "node2",  
  "node3",
]);

var vm = {
  data: data,
  expand: function(parentArray, i) {
    var fakeAjaxData = ["node1", "node2", "node3"];
    parentArray.splice(i+1, 0, fakeAjaxData);
    data.valueHasMutated();
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<style>li {cursor: pointer}</style>
<div data-bind='component: {name: "myList", params: data}'></div>
```